# Intersection Set Theory Proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathbb{R}$ denote the set of real numbers and $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$. If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$ let $(a,b) = \{r \in \mathbb{R} : a<r<b\}$.

Prove: 
$$
\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (0, 1/n) = \varnothing
$$

You may use standard facts about real number inequalities and arithmetic, such as:

1) Given $a,b,t \in \mathbb{R}$ with $t > 0$, if $a < b$ then $ta < tb$.

2) For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k > x$.

the way I've started it, is I've let x be an element of R(the real numbers), I know I need to split it into 2 parts, x>0 and x<=0, and no matter which positive x I pick, theres a set that excludes it because 1/n is smaller.  so that means x isn't in all of the sets.  Am I on the right track?  If so, how do I put these together to make my proof look good?  Thanks.

Comment: If you're studying mathematics, and especially if you're going to ask questions here, it's worth your time to learn some $\LaTeX$:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#Examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're essentially right.

A more formal proof would say:

Let $x\in\mathbb R$ be positive; in this case $\frac1x$ is also a possitive real number.  By 2. we know there is $k\in\mathbb N$ such as $k>\frac1x$, and therefor $\frac1k<x$. (If you prefer you can say, let's $t=x$ and apply 1. so $k>\frac1x \implies kx>1$; now make $k=\frac1k$ and apply 1. again so $kx>1\implies x>\frac1k$, therefor $k>\frac1x\implies x>\frac1k$).

With this result, then we know that $x\notin(0,\frac1k)$, and therefor $x\notin (0,\frac1k)\cap\text{anything}$, so $x\notin\bigcap(1,\frac1n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by contradiction: assume that the intersection is not empty, hence there is at least one $x$ contained in all the $(0,1/n)$ intervals, but this is not possible because you can always find an $n$ such that $1/n < x$

Answer (score 0):

Because the sets $(0, \frac{1}{n})$ never contain negative numbers or 0, you only need to consider the case when $x>0$.

I think you're doing this already, but you should state that you're going to prove $$ \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(0, \frac{1}{n}\right) = \emptyset$$ by contradiction. So assume there *is* some $x$ in that intersection, and use the fact that eventually $\frac1n$ will be smaller than any $x$ (and explain why you know this). You're on your way to a good proof.